# BookshelfJS: findOrCreate function returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

I found in the [github issue 21](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/21#issuecomment-19619420) in the bookshelf repo this findOrCreate function:

```
    module.exports = bookshelf.model('Exercise', {
        tableName: 'exercises',
        hasTimestamps: true,
        findOrCreate = function(options) {
              var cloned = this.clone();
              return this.fetch(_.extend(options, {require: true})).then(null, function(err) {
                 if (err.message === 'EmptyResponse') return cloned.save();
                 throw err;
              });
        }
```

But when i want to use the findOrCreate method with a new entry, the function return null.

```
    Exercise.forge({
            name: 'Testqqqq',
            user_id: 1
    }).findOrCreate().then(function(ex) {
            console.log(ex); //null for new one, should return the new model
    });
```

For a existing one it is working. Is there something wrong with the promisses?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it to check if the result of the find is null

```
findOrCreate: function(options) {
      var cloned = this.clone();
      return this.fetch(_.extend(options, {require: true})).then(function(result) {
         if (result === null) return cloned.save();
         return result;
      });
}
```